# In Google Sheets, how to list and sum values in some rows but not others depending on string?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to join gained level for names in a list.
Some names are the same person who has changed handle and the scores should be summed.

I have created a sheet to track levels for players in rankings over time.
My implementation is not as clever as I would like it to be.
Also, there is a problem with some players changing names.

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGv1Mks1ExRzuQVxsc7cPepyA3kFm8nBL6PQW0IBOAQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Currently, I have

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({}))
```

In order to produce just one of each name in a list
In the cell next to that I'm using

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH())) + IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH())) + IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH()))
```

to the sum of levels for each name across several ranges /sessions.

In the example sheet, **N7** and **N10** is the same person but my SORT, INDEX, as well as QUERY cannot handle this. I would like to (manually type in the names as strings that belong to the same person) and that the latest handle is the one used in query output together with the sum of all gains.

Any direction pointers or suggestions as to how I could improve my current implementation or even solve the problem I'm having would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Ranking!CF4:CF200\ SUBSTITUTE(Ranking!CG4:CG200; "N7"; "N10")}; 
 "select Col2,sum(Col1)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col2
  label sum(Col1)'',Col2'Total levels gained since 15 April 2018'"; 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for.
Is it possible to use several substitutions in the same query? (I failed).
Do you also happen to have a clever improvement on CF4? I think it is ugly but could not think of a better way for now.

Comment: **CF4**: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(CG4:CG); 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CG4:CG; {BK4:BK\BN4:BN}; 2; 0))+
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CG4:CG; {BP4:BP\BS4:BS}; 2; 0))+
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CG4:CG; {BU4:BU\BX4:BX}; 2; 0)); ))`

Comment: sure, like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Ranking!CF4:CF200\ SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Ranking!CG4:CG200; "N7"; "N10"); "N15"; "N1")}; 
 "select Col2,sum(Col1)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col2
  label sum(Col1)'',Col2'Total levels gained since 15 April 2018'"; 0))`

Comment: Spot on again. Thank you. The natural question to this must be; Happen to have a source for someone hungry to learn to use these things? Google is great for the generic cases but I often find myself lacking finesse.

Comment: nope, no resources... just a google sheet and endless testing of stuff until I crack it

Answer (score 0):

Might not suit you (could mean an extra column per month) but *one* way would be to to use a lookup table. That is enter whatever name suits you, lookup the 'standard' for that name and drive further analysis off that.

Comment: Unsure how that would make a difference on the end result though, I would still have to sum the values from them all with different names?
And would also have to maintain a master list of names that belong to the same user?